# Frobenius theorem and the size of integral manifold

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, differential-equations

Let $X =(X_0,X_1)\in \mathbb{R}^2$ and $Y=(Y_0,Y_1)\in \mathbb{R}^2$ be two vector fields on $\mathbb{R}^2$ such that $X,Y$ are independent on each tangent plane and
$[X,Y]:=XY-YX=0$.
Then by Frobenius theorem, the partial differential equation on $\mathbb{R}^2$ given by
$\frac{d}{ds}f=X_0(f(s,t),g(s,t)),\frac{d}{ds}g=X_1(f(s,t),g(s,t))$,
$\frac{d}{dt}f=Y_0(f(s,t),g(s,t)),\frac{d}{dt}g=Y_1(f(s,t),g(s,t))$,
$ (f(0,0),g(0,0))=(0,0)$
has a solution in $-\epsilon<s<\epsilon,-\epsilon<t<\epsilon$ for some positive real number $\epsilon$.

My question is if $f,g$ are maximal solutions (i.e $f,g$ cannot be extended) then is the image of $(f(s,t),g(s,t))$ equal to the whole $\mathbb{R}^2$?

edit
I'm especially curious about the case when $X_0,X_1,Y_0,Y_1$ are polynomials.

Answer (score 5):

Your equations are equivalent to the $1$-form equations
$$
\mathrm{d}f = X_0(f,g)\,\mathrm{d}s + Y_0(f,g)\,\mathrm{d}t 
\quad \text{and}\quad  
\mathrm{d}g = X_1(f,g)\,\mathrm{d}s + Y_1(f,g)\,\mathrm{d}t 
$$
The Frobenius compatibility condition for these two $1$-form equations is indeed the condition that $[X,Y]=0$, where, in the $uv$-plane
$$
X = X_0(u,v)\,\frac{\partial}{\partial u} + X_1(u,v)\,\frac{\partial}{\partial v}\quad \text{and}\quad  
Y = Y_0(u,v)\,\frac{\partial}{\partial u} + Y_1(u,v)\,\frac{\partial}{\partial v}\,.
$$

Note that, setting
$$
\begin{aligned}
X_0(u,v)&=\phantom{-}e^{-u}\cos(v),&& Y_0(u,v)=e^{-u}\sin(v),\\ 
X_1(u,v)&=-e^{-u}\sin(v),&& Y_1(u,v)=e^{-u}\cos(v),
\end{aligned}
$$
we get an example (not polynomial, though), for which it turns out that there are maximal solutions (f,g) satisfying your initial conditions for which the range of $(f,g)$ is not all of $\mathbb{R}^2$.  (Maximal solutions are not unique.). The point is that a solution satisfying your initial condition also satisfies
$$
s = e^f\cos g - 1\quad\text{and}\quad t = e^f\sin g,
$$
and these equations are equivalent to the complex equation
$$
1+ s + i t = e^{f+ig},
$$
so $f+i g$ must be a branch of $\log (1 + s+it)$, which cannot be global.
There is a unique solution on the complement of the ray $t=0$ and $s\le-1$, and if you look at that solution, you will see that $f+ig$ does not map this open set onto the complex plane, in fact, $|g|\le \pi$.

Comment: I think $X$ and $Y$ aren't linearly independent where $sin(v)=cos(v)$.

Comment: Should we choose $Y_1=e^{-u}\cos(v)$?

Comment: @George:  You are correct.  That minus sign was an error on my part (caused by my miscopying the formula).  I have fixed it now.